# Object Casting Error

Tags: vb.net, background-color, datetimepicker

Show error Unable to cast object of type 'system.windows.forms.combobox' to type 'system.windows.form.DateTimePicker' on my code...

```
Private Sub UncheckMyControlsdtp()
    Dim dtp As DateTimePicker
    Try
        For Each dtp In EMPGBDATA.Controls
            If dtp.CalendarMonthBackground = Color.Red Then
                dtp.CalendarMonthBackground = Color.White
            End If
        Next
    Catch e As Exception
        MsgBox(e.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Friends check my code and give solution...

Comment: what is the type of ctrl??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check the the controls you are enumerating from `EMPGBDATA.Controls` are of type `DateTimePicker`:

```
Private Sub UncheckMyControlsdtp()
    Try
        For Each ctrl In EMPGBDATA.Controls
            If TypeOf ctrl Is DateTimePicker Then
                Dim dtp As DateTimePicker = CType(ctrl, DateTimePicker)
                If dtp.CalendarMonthBackground = Color.Red Then
                    dtp.CalendarMonthBackground = Color.White
                End If
            End If
        Next
    Catch e As Exception
        MsgBox(e.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: what is the type of ctrl??

Comment: It's checking whether the type of the current control in the loop is a DateTimePicker, so it doesn't try running the code on something that isn't a DateTimePicker control.

Comment: @Thanzeem: The type of ctrl is `Control`: `For Each ctrl As Control In EMPGBDATA.Controls`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're iterating all of the controls in `EMPGBDATA.Controls`, some of which aren't instances of `DateTimePicker`. You're going to have to manually check inside the `For Each` loop to make sure the instance is the right type. Like this:

```
Private Sub UncheckMyControlsdtp()
    For Each ctl As Control In EMPGBDATA.Controls
        If TypeOf ctl Is DateTimePicker Then
            Dim dtp As DateTimePicker = DirectCast(ctl, DateTimePicker)

            If dtp.CalendarMonthBackground = Color.Red Then
                dtp.CalendarMonthBackground = Color.White
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```